# Qt5 MYSQL "open()" method return true even with wrong credentials

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, qt5

While writing a Qt5 application that uses `QSqlDatabase` with MySQL, I encountered a strange bug when I try to connect to datebase. `QSqlDatabase::open()` returns true even with wrong username, password and port. That's my code:

```
QSqlDatabase DB = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", "Connection");
DB.setHostName(Interface.InputIP->text());
DB.setDatabaseName("connectdb");
DB.setPort(Interface.InputPort->value());
DB.setUserName(Interface.InputLog->text());
DB.setPassword(Interface.InputPass->text());
bool result = DB.open();
if(result)
    QMessageBox::information(0, "Success", "Connected");
else
    QMessageBox::information(0, "Error", DB.lastError().text());
DB.close();
```

Is it possible to avoid that bug?

Comment: Is this really a bug? Did you find it on http://bugreports.qt.io/ ? Just this kind of questions more look like a bugreport.